# insuring CPU time after waking up - linux scheduler

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduling

I'm running in a driver's context in linux kernel - this driver writes a value to a register - an operation which takes some time (~5 msec). I would like to sleep during that time in order to give away the CPU to other threads - but it is very important to me to have the CPU back immediatelly after I wake up (there's a short timeout which I must not exceed).
Same question goes for taking a mutex - say I'm blocking on a mutex (and triggering a re-schedule) - how can insure that I'll get the CPU back immediatelly when that mutex is released?

Is there a way to do this? what does it involve? (setting priority to the process? special scheduling mode? changing kernel config?)

EDIT: 
I'll rephrase the question about the mutex since it's a bit more complicated:
I have a mutex which is used by important threads (important because of that timeout limit). I would like to take this mutex, knowing that if I will block on it and get reschduled, the lock will be be released quickly (because these threads will have a high priority), and immediatelly after that, my blocked thread will be able to run (and not some other, unrelated program).
This way I can save CPU time while not risking a timeout violation.
I currently use busy waiting in order to avoid rescheduling (my kernel is non preemptive) but I don't like this solution.

Any help will be appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you are observing delays while writing. I think in this situation you can use
`schedule_timeout` function. Device drivers use this technique while writing to register so that they dont lockup the system. Recently, I have come across a problem where writing to register is causing delays; I am planning to do `schedule_timeout` in my case too.

Setting priority, scheduling mode will not help here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll definitely check it out. Do you have a suggestion for the mutex case? (getting the CPU back immediately when the lock is being released?)